# eclipse doesn't create java classes from wsdl into current project

Tags: eclipse, wsdl

I've read other answers and various forums but no one has my same problem.

I use Eclipse Juno EE. I've a Java project. When I right-click on project and create new wsdl client, it doesn't create java classes in my project but it attempt to create a new project.

If you look the image, if I click on client project, it doesn't show my project but that WebServiceProject...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created new black web project, imported successfully and copy and past classes. Not perfect solution but unique for me.